# Is it possible to lower the fares through Amadeus?

Tags: tickets, fares, gds

Can we make the fares cheaper through the GDS system (Amadeus)? Frequently I see that the fares from the officials sites like Qatar, Turkish, Lufthansa etc. are even cheaper from my GDS. I'm talking about the same classes, flights routes with the same schedule.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Rashid, please include more details, with some examples. Your question might be interesting for the community but as it is, it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Just for clarification, you mean the price is lower on the official sites compared to what you see on your GDS (I suppose you're a travel agent)?

Comment: Yes, the prices are always much higher than the prices from my GDS system. I'm new in this sphere, but I recognise that more and more people prefer to buy directly from Sky Skanner and other sites rather than us.  Why sites like Opodo and Sky Skanner have more cheap prices even than official sites ? Did they have some agreements or ?

Answer (score 4):

Airlines frequently offer lower fares on their websites than they do through GDSes, simply because they want to encourage brand loyalty and discourage price shopping.

Under some circumstances, you may be able to get as low or nearly as low a fare through a booking agency, depending on when you book, your booking currency, etc. Aggregator sites like Kayak and Skyscanner can sometimes help with this; I've even had situations where finding a flight on Skyscanner and then linking through it to book from the airline's website was *cheaper than when finding the same flight on the airline website.*

But there's no way to tell Amadeus or whatever "the airline quoted me that fare over there, so please give me the same fare here". Airlines are free to make whatever offers they want, wherever they want, and to make different offers in different places. And sometimes, frequently, *usually*, they play around with that.

Comment: While I don't think this applies to the airlines quoted by OP, some also don't publish all their fares on GDSes, either because they can't (don't fit in the class-fare-fare bucket system), or because they don't want to (they want to sell extras and the GDSes are not the best way to do that). See for example American Airlines [here](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage/2115996-corporate-travel-about-get-harder-lower-fares-removed-legacy-gds.html) and [here](https://www.travelweekly.com/Travel-News/Airline-News/American-plans-NDC-acceleration).

Comment: @jcaron Amadeus support NDC, as do most (all?) other GDS's. They may not support it for every airline, but they definitely do for the majors, including AA.

Comment: What is the purpose than from GDS's systems and what will be the future of selling tickets ?  How can I offer prices while in the official sites the prices are cheaper and everyone can use aggregates like Sky Skanner and etc... ( Thanks for the Answers )